Pointer to abominable function type? Compiler bug?
According to C++23 what is FTDecay<int()&>?
template <class Signature>
struct Decompose;

template <class T>
struct Decompose<void(T)> {
    using Type = T;
};

template <class T>
using FTDecay = typename Decompose<void(T)>::Type;


FTDecay<int()&> x = "Hello";

In current MSVC, Clang and GCC implementations the last line above generates error messages that mention an ill-formed type int (*)() & (demo). GCC says:
error: cannot convert 'const char*' to 'FTDecay<int() &>' {aka 'int (*)() &'}
       in initialization

P0172r0 says it is ill-formed (diagnostic required) to form a reference or a pointer to an abominable function type. The paper introduces this term; it means a function type followed by a cv-ref qualifier. Accordingly, using X = int (*)() &; is rejected by all compilers (demo).

don't title questions with terms that people don't know unless they've read some paper

FTDecay<int()&> is int (*)() &. See the explanation given in the answer below. Because int()& is a function-type as explained in this old answer, it decays to int(*)()&. Thus Type=T=int(*)()& which is what FTDecay<int()&> is.

@xaxxon How else should this question be titled? The title exactly and concisely reflects OP's question. The question is, specifically, about OP starting with an abominable function type and it turning into a pointer to that

@barry I'd suggest the actual function type as opposed to an esoteric adjective.

@xaxxon That is the name of the function type though. Yes, it's an esoteric term - but that is the term.

Here is the CWG issue that explains that this is ill-formed and intended to be ill-formed with or without initializer. Here is the gcc bug

Here is the clang bug.

[dcl.fct]p5


[...] After determining the type of each parameter, any parameter of type “array of T” or of function type T is adjusted to be “pointer to T”. [...]


[dcl.ptr]p4


[Note 1: [...]
Forming a function pointer type is ill-formed if the function type has cv-qualifiers or a ref-qualifier; see [dcl.fct]. [...]]


This is a non-normative note, but is based on [dcl.fct]p10


A function type with a cv-qualifier-seq or a ref-qualifier (including a type named by typedef-name ([dcl.typedef], [temp.param])) shall appear only as:

the function type for a non-static member function,
the function type to which a pointer to member refers,
the top-level function type of a function typedef declaration or alias-declaration,
the type-id in the default argument of a type-parameter ([temp.param]), or
the type-id of a template-argument for a type-parameter ([temp.arg.type]).




... Where none of those bullets are "the type pointed to by a pointer type" or similar.

Therefore, void(T) adjusts T which has function type void() & to "pointer to void() &", which is ill-formed.
This would be a SNIFE-able error, but FTDecay<int()&> is ill-formed because Decompose<void(T)> is ill-formed. This is a compiler bug in Clang and GCC that a pointer to ref-qualified function type is formed in the first place and a bug in MSVC that the error isn't early enough (it seems to just pick the default specialization, and doesn't adjust the function type to a pointer to make it an error: https://godbolt.org/z/M9nEzoeET)

I suggest reporting those bugs...

All compilers accept the code without the = "Hello" initializer. MSVC v19.40 (not yet available on godbolt.org) also accepts it. We can add, that the standard is not clear enough on this.

@​HolyBlackCat There was already a GCC bug here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69898 and a Clang bug here: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/27059 . A bug for MSVC was filed which they deemed to be not a bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/10637080 (which I don't agree with)

@Dr.Gut It appears clear that pointers to abominable function types is ill-formed and a parameter which initially has an abominable function type must be adjusted to a pointer to an abominable function type. Seems pretty clear to me that this should be ill-formed

@Dr.Gut No, the standard is pretty clear that the program is ill-formed as I've already explained many times.
